# Как вывести предложение с каждым словом в обратном порядке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

не знаю как правильно написать код

`def backwards(sentence: str) -> str:`

`backwards('hello python')`

совсем запутался, не понимаю как вывести правильно, выход должен быть таким:

`'olleh nohtyp'`

буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: `print(*[ w[::-1] for w in 'hello python'.split() ], end=' ')`

Comment: Нужно есть слона кусками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def backwards(sentence: str) -> str:
    return ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in sentence.split())
```

Answer (score 2):

вариант 1:

```
' '.join(i[::-1] for i in text.split())
```

вариант 2:

```
' '.join(map(lambda i: i[::-1], text.split()))
```

вариант 3:

```
' '.join(map(''.join, map(reversed, text.split())))
```

вариант 4 (**самый короткий**):

```
' '.join(reversed(text[::-1].split()))
```

вариант 5:

```
' '.join(reversed(''.join(reversed(text)).split()))
```